# antlr4: code production vs visitors

Tags: optimization, antlr4, production, visitors

My grammar contains production code.
Is it really possible to mix this with visitors ? (my problem is to implement if cond then block endif )

In terms of performances, is there a difference between production code in grammar vs visitors ? (I have to re-evaluate several programs 30-60 times per second, in the browser on Javascript target. I understood direct production code was closer to compiled code but maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: What is meant by `production code`?  Actions that directly produce output?

Comment: when you have code directly in the g4 file. E.g.:

e returns [float v]

    : a=e op=('*'|'/''|+'|'-') b=e      { $v = myeval($a.v, $op.type, $b.v); }

    | 'max' '(' a=e ',' b=e ')'         { $v = Math.max($a.v, $b.v); }

...

Answer (score 1):

Actions of the type shown only affect the content of the parse-tree -- an `e` context node will be created with a return field having the Action computed value. Consequently, there is no bar to subsequently walking the parse tree with a visitor.

Using a visitor (without using the embedded Actions) can achieve the same end results.

Using a visitor will incur some overhead - impossible to say whether it would be significant without testing (using the Java/Antlr runtime, evaluating a relatively complex grammar with multiple walkers over a fairly lengthy source text, takes 3ms average in a warm environment - YMWV).

Comment: Yes these actions have limited scope. But now I have to implement if/then/else. People seems to tell that it is now impossible to do it that way (it was, on earlier version of Antlr :-( ). And that I should use visitors for that (I still don't know how). Here, I wanted to first know whether it is possible to use visitors ONLY for if/then/else and to keep the rest of the production code the way it is.

Comment: Short answer is Yes, you can use both techniques at the same time.  Antlr4 tends to favor using walkers for certain operations, such as if/then/else, but that in no way precludes or limits using actions in any grammar rules.

Comment: ok.
BTW, do you think it would still be possible to implement if/then/else as actions ? In my old Antlr2.7 program I try to adapt with minimal work it was simply obtain by   : #("if" cond=F:fexpr)
        {
            if( cond != 0.0 )
     {
                if( F->getNextSibling() )
      if( F->getNextSibling()->getFirstChild() )
   start(F->getNextSibling()->getFirstChild());
     }
     else
                if( F->getNextSibling() ) 
      if( F->getNextSibling()->getNextSibling() )     
   start( F->getNextSibling()->getNextSibling() );    
        }

Comment: Imagine it is possible, but you are fighting against Antlr4's strengths. In trying to minimize work, you are likely creating an implementation and maintenance nightmare.  What you proposed actually hard-codes the structure of the parse tree back into the grammar! That type of fragility is exactly what Antlr4 strives to avoid. You will save far more time and effort by updating your program to use a proper idiomatic Antlr4 grammar and walkers. IMO.

Comment: I am a senior engineer and adult. I know my projects, time schedule, I have "some" experience. I do arbitrations and choices. Coding style opinions must never be turned into absolutist religion and ideology : circonstances also exists. Here, I am trying to make an old code (used by users) survive by passing to web, with very little available resources to do the job. It's complex, almost there, but this little point. Should I really trash the whole thing, or modify other professional projects priorities, just to conform to this "ideal" ? ideal should be an inspiration, not a brake, wall or jail

Comment: Moreover, ANTLR4 pretend to "make life more easy for users". The fact is that here, after weeks of searching, I couldn't find usable tutos or examples of how doing "the recommanded way". Compare the number of lines it takes the old and new way. Compare the depth of knowledge it takes the old and new way. Not all applications are ultra-deep demanding grammars. Please, please, allow some non-ultra-specialized-expert in grammars the possibility to use tools. Especially, drastically changing the expertise requirement between 2 versions of the same product is evil.

Comment: Perhaps your question should have been "Is there any compelling reason to upgrade a working grammar from Antlr 2.7 to 4.5, given limited time, resources and flexibility?"  The answer to that question is no.  If Antlr2.7 works for you, there is no reason not to continue using it.  BTW, Antlr has never made a commitment to backward compatibility between major versions. Each major version has seen a significant improvement in usability and maintainability, though requiring a change in design mind set.  Many legacy projects continue to quite successfully use legacy Antlr versions.

Comment: No the question is not that one, but the one I asked. The purpose is to transfer the code to the JS target, which seems to force to use Antlr4.
The code has many other aspects that could be adapted. Most of the grammar could be simply adapted as well. I'm just stuck for the if/then/else, with no clue of how to do this either the old way or the new way.